# Excel ignore blank cells with date subtraction in a MIN array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to find the smallest difference between 2 sets of dates.

The most simple array formula sort of works and finds the smallest difference, but if 1 of the columns is missing a date, it treats the blank cell as 0 and the result of MIN difference in days becomes something like -42634 (which is not what I want).

```
{=MIN(X23:X95-P23:P95)}
```

After some reading, I tried to subtract only if both columns is not blank and while it works with a single row...

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(X23),ISBLANK(P23)),"",X23-P23)
```

it returns a `#VALUE!` error if I try wrapping it with `MIN`...

```
=MIN(IF(OR(ISBLANK(X23),ISBLANK(P23)),"",X23-P23))
```

I'm no Excel expert, but I'm guessing it's because a `MIN` of nothing but blank cells is going to throw an error as I read it's supposed to ignore blanks. Using `MIN`/`MAX` on 2 cells with one containing a date and the other blank seems to confirm this as it results in the only date.

I tried to incorporate this into the original formula, but I have no idea what I'm doing and I end up getting a `#VALUE!` error again. Help?

```
{=MIN(IF(OR(ISBLANK(X23:X95),ISBLANK(P23:P95)),"",X23:X95-P23:P95))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` evaluates ALL of its parameters to ONE RESULT (not just pairwise).

To evaluate it as you need use
`IF(ISBLANK(X23:X95)+ISBLANK(P23:P95)...`

Tip: to better understand your formula you can evaluate it and see results step by step in Formula - "Evaluate formula"

### Edit

Using `+`,`-`,`/`,`*` operators Excel automatically converts boolean to integers (True -> 1; False -> 0), so addition (`+`) works similar as OR, and multiplication (`*`) works as AND.
After, `IF` converts numbers back to boolean (0 -> False, non-zero -> True).

Comment: I don't quiet understand the "+" sign, but your solution seems to be working.

Comment: please see my update, I've tried to explain it.